# Angular Emptying A Shopping Cart

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Hello I have a shopping cart which I am able to add products as well as delete products using a **api** . When deleting an item from cart it has to be deleted using a button click on each item by id, one by one. which is fine for that purpose, but I am trying to do empty all items in cart url from a function not a button which has not worked for me because id will be undefined.

My question is, if this is even possible?  I have tried clearing the array of items such as cartItems.length = 0  or cartItems = [] this only empties a copy of the array from my understanding, so therefore the items will still exist in the cart from what I have tried.

I'm reaching out to see if anyone can answer this and point me in the right direction it will be greatly appreciated.  I have included a snippet of of html and the cart service for the delete item.

cart service

```
 RemoveProductFromCart(id:number):Observable<void>{
     return this.http.delete<CartItem[]>(`${this.cartUrl}/${id}`)
     .pipe(catchError(_err => of (null))
      
     );
    }
```

cartitem.ts

```
 handleRemoveFromCart(){
        alert("hit remove from cart");
          
 this.cartService.RemoveProductFromCart(this.cartItem.id)
 .subscribe(() =>
        console.log("Product with Id deleted", 
      this.cartItem.id),
        (err) => console.log(err)
        );
      
       
       
      }
```

html for cartitem

```
<div class="container-md" >
   <div>
    <img class="img-fluid" [src]="cartItem.imageUrl" style="padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:50px" alt="Cart">     
      <div class="text-nowrap" style="font-size:13px; width: 400px">{{cartItem.productName}}</div> 
     {{cartItem?.size}}{{Valuesize}}
   
   <div style="font-size:13px;"><strong>{{ (cartItem.price) | currency}}</strong></div>
  <div class=" float-right">
   <span><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can" style="color:#D30169; cursor: pointer;" (click)="handleRemoveFromCart();handleReload()"></i></span>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

cart html

```
<div *ngIf="cartItems.length === 0"class="alert alert- 
      info">Your Cart is Empty</div> 
    
    <div *ngIf="product">
      <div>{{product.name}}</div>
      <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="product.num" 
        min="0"/>
    </div>   
      <div  *ngFor="let item of cartItems; let i = index">
        <app-cart-item  [cartItem]="item"></app-cart-item>  
      </div>
      
      <li class="list-group-item" style="margin-top:30px;">
       <strong>Total Items {{itemTotal}}</strong>
      </li> 
      <li class="list-group-item active">
        <strong>Total: {{ cartTotal | currency}}</strong>  
      </li>
      <li class="btn btn-primary" style="height: 40px; 
        width:210px; margin-top:20px; color:ffffff">
        <a class=""  routerLink="/clothing" style="color: 
         #ffffff; cursor: pointer;">Continue   
         Shopping</a>&nbsp; 
     </li>
      <li class= "btn" style="height: 40px; width:210px; 
         margin-top: 20px; background-color:#D30169">
        <a class="" routerLink="/checkout" style="color: 
          #ffffff">Go To Checkout</a>&nbsp; 
      </li>
      
    </div>
    </div>
    </div
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [Rxjs](https://rxjs.dev/)

**cart.service.ts**

Create a behavior subject of cart items

```
cartItems$ = new BehaviorSubject<CartItem>([]);
```

To clear all the items

```
  clearCart() {
    this.cartItems$.next([]);
  }
```

To add or remove an item

```
  addToCart(cartItem: CartItem) {
    this.cartItems$.next([cartItem, ...this.cartItems.getValue()]);
  }

  removeFromCart(cartItemId: string) {
    this.cartItems$.next([this.cartItems.getValue().filter((cartItem) => cartItem.id !== cartItemId)]);
  }
```

**cartItem.ts**

To subscribe to cartItems

```
  cartItems:CartItem[] = []

  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {
    this.cartService.cartItems$.subscribe((v) => (this.cartItems = v));
  }
```

---

Don't forget to unsubscribe

Comment: Should the BehaviorSubject be  cartItems$ = new BehaviorSubject<CartItem[]>([]); yours has  cartItems$ = new BehaviorSubject<CartItem>([]); I get an error it complains missing all the items in tthe model/interface

Comment: @user2280852 Oh yes. it should be  `<CartItem[]>`

Comment: I have another question for you, in you snippets you gave me I guess it is save to say that I can delete with out using a button click with this type of functionality?

Comment: yes. Just call `clearCart()` wherever u want to clear the cart

Comment: This is awesome!  I'm testing it out now, will comment when I get it working.

Comment: Hello this didn't work for me. as mention I'm using api db.json    "cart": [
             {
      "product": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Overalls",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
        "imageUrl": "http://localhost:4200/assets/overalls.png",
        "price": 250
      },
      "id": 2
    }
  ],                      any ideas